# Transfer captured map into another template using visio

Tags: dictionary, process, flowchart

Transfer ℹ️ from a map to another template applying swimlane, appropriate symbols.

Using visio to clean up a process map. I have a template that the other map needs to be converted to. Appropriate symbols, one action per step, general clean up.
Use the symbolization from the glossary.